# Find minimum cost of tickets

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

Find minimum cost of tickets required to buy for traveling on known days of the month (1...30). Three types of tickets are available : 1-day ticket valid for 1 days and costs 2 units, 7-days ticket valid for 7 days and costs 7 units, 30-days ticket valid for 30 days and costs 25 units.

For eg: I want to travel on [1,4,6,7,28,30] days of the month i.e. 1st, 4th, 6th ... day of the month. How to buy tickets so that the cost is minimum.

I tried to use dynamic programming to solve this but the solution is not giving me the correct answer for all cases. Here is my solution in Java :

```
public class TicketsCost {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] arr  =  {1,5,6,9,28,30};
        System.out.println(findMinCost(arr));
    }
    public static int findMinCost(int[] arr) {
        int[][] dp = new int[arr.length][3];
        int[] tDays = {1,7,30};
        int[] tCost = {2,7,25};

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (j==0){
                    dp[i][j]= (i+1)*tCost[j];
                }
                else{
                    int c = arr[i]-tDays[j];
                    int tempCost = tCost[j];
                    int k;
                    if (c>=arr[0] && i>0){
                        for (k = i-1; k >= 0; k--) {
                            if (arr[k]<=c){
                                c = arr[k];
                            }
                        }
                        tempCost += dp[c][j];
                        int tempCostX =  dp[i-1][j] + tCost[0];
                        tempCost = Math.min(tempCost,tempCostX);

                    }
                    dp[i][j] = Math.min(tempCost,dp[i][j-1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[arr.length-1][2];
    }
}
```

The solution doesn't work for {1,7,8,9,10} input, it gives 10 but the correct answer should be 9. Also, for {1,7,8,9,10,15} it give 13 but the correct is 11. 
I have posted my solution not for other to debug it for me but just for reference. I was taken a bottom-up dynamic programming approach for this problem. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Please cite a specific case it fails on.

Comment: *the solution is not giving me the correct answer for all cases*. Are we supposed to just somehow test *all cases* to figure out what you're asking? What **specific problem** are you having with the code you've posted, and what **specific cases** fail that we can use to try to help? We're not psychic, and we can't see your screen from where we're sitting either. If you want help, provide the details that we need to provide it to you.

Comment: I just want to know the correct approach for this problem. Have not pasted the code for others to debug.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved using the same approach of bottom-up dynamic programming. Here is the full solution :

```
public class PublicTicketCost {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] arr  =  {1,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18,21,25};
        int[] tDays = {1,7,30};
        int[] tCost = {2,7,25};
        System.out.println(minCost(arr, tDays, tCost));
    }
    public static int minCost(int[] arr, int[] tDays, int[] tCost) {
        int[][] dp = new int[arr.length][tDays.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tDays.length; j++) {

                int prevDayIndex = findPrevDayIndex(arr,i,tDays,j);
                int prevCost = prevDayIndex>=0 ? dp[prevDayIndex][tDays.length-1] : 0;
                int currCost = prevCost + tCost[j];
                if(j-1>=0){
                    currCost = Math.min(currCost, dp[i][j-1]);
                }
                dp[i][j] = currCost;
            }
        }
        //print(dp);
        return dp[arr.length-1][tDays.length-1];
    }
    private static void print(int arr[][]){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    private static int findPrevDayIndex(int[] arr, int i, int[] days, int j){
        int validAfterDate = arr[i] - days[j];
        if (validAfterDate<1){
            return -1;
        }
        for (int k = i-1; k >= 0; k--) {
            if (arr[k]<=validAfterDate){
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/sfgxGo

Answer (score 10):

Let MC(*d*) denote the minimum cost that will pay for all trips on days 1 through *d*. The desired answer is then MC(30).

To calculate MC(*d*), observe the following:

- If there's no trip on day *d*, then MC(*d*) = MC(*d* − 1).

  - As a special case, MC(*d*) = 0 for all *d* ≤ 0.
- Otherwise, the minimum cost involves one of the following:

  - A 1-day pass on day *d*. In this case, MC(*d*) = MC(*d* − 1) + 2.
  - A 7-day pass ending on or after day *d*. In this case, MC(*d*) = min(MC(*d* − 7), MC(*d* − 6), …, MC(*d* − 1)) + 7.

    - And since MC is nondecreasing (adding a day never reduces the minimum cost), this can be simplified to MC(*d*) = MC(*d* − 7) + 7. (Hat-tip to [Ravi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3423104/ravi) for pointing this out.)
  - A 30-day pass covering the whole period. In this case, MC(*d*) = 25.

As you've realized, dynamic programming (bottom-up recursion) is well-suited to this.

For ease of coding, I suggest we start by converting the list of days into a lookup table for "is this a trip day?":

```
boolean[] isDayWithTrip = new boolean[31]; // note: initializes to false
for (final int dayWithTrip : arr) {
    isDayWithTrip[dayWithTrip] = true;
}
```

We can then create an array to track the minimum costs, and populate it starting from index 0:

```
int[] minCostUpThroughDay = new int[31];
minCostUpThroughDay[0] = 0; // technically redundant
for (int d = 1; d <= 30; ++d) {
    if (! isDayWithTrip[d]) {
        minCostUpThroughDay[d] = minCostUpThroughDay[d-1];
        continue;
    }

    int minCost;
    // Possibility #1: one-day pass on day d:
    minCost = minCostUpThroughDay[d-1] + 2;
    // Possibility #2: seven-day pass ending on or after day d:
    minCost =
        Math.min(minCost, minCostUpThroughDay[Math.max(0, d-7)] + 7);
    // Possibility #3: 30-day pass for the whole period:
    minCost = Math.min(minCost, 25);

    minCostUpThroughDay[d] = minCost;
}
```

And `minCostUpThroughDay[30]` is the result.

You can see the above code in action at: https://ideone.com/1Xx1fd.

Comment: Thanks. I have also posted my solution below, if possible please have a look.

Comment: Just wondering what if I'd rather use value of prevD directly as `(d-7)` (obviously after checking `d >= 7`) rather than taking a range from `Math.max(0, d - 7)` to `d - 4`; and get rid of the for loop.

Comment: @Ravi: You're quite right; it's guaranteed that `minCostUpThroughDay` is nondecreasing, so we know that `minCostUpThroughDay[Math.max(0, d-7)]` will be the least value in that range. I'll update.

Comment: @ruakh, I couldn't understand the 7 day logic though, why/how did you come up with `MC(d) = min(MC(d − 7), MC(d − 6), …, MC(d − 1)) + 7. `?

Answer (score 1):

One recursive solution in Python3.

```py
from typing import List


def solution(A: List[int]) -> int:
    if not any(A):
        return 0

    tickets = {
        1: 2,
        7: 7,
        30: 25,
    }

    import sys
    min_cost = sys.maxsize
    size = len(A)

    for length, price in tickets.items():
        current_cost = price
        idx = 0

        last_day = A[idx] + length

        while idx < size and A[idx] < last_day:
            idx += 1

        if current_cost > min_cost:
            continue

        current_cost += solution(A[idx:])
        if current_cost < min_cost:
            min_cost = current_cost

    return min_cost


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cases = {
        11: [1, 4, 6, 7, 28, 30],
        9: [1, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    }

    for expect, parameters in cases.items():
        status = (expect == solution(parameters))
        print("case pass status: %s, detail: %s == solution(%s)" %
              (status, expect, parameters))
```

Comment: This is a good solution. As an improvement suggestion, the variable `cases` should be a list of tuple instead of a dictionary. For example: `cases = [(11,[1,4,6,7,28,30]), (11,[1,3,5,8,9,10])]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main03v3
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] A = {1,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,18,21,25};

    System.out.println("Traveling days:\r\n "+Arrays.toString(A));
    int cost = solution(A);
    System.out.println("\r\nMinimum cost is " + cost);
    System.out.println("\r\n" + new String(new char[40]).replace("\0", "-"));
  }

  public static int solution(int[] A) 
  {
    if (A == null) return -1;

    int sevenDays = 7;
    int dayCost = 2, weekCost = 7, monthCost = 25;
    int ratio_WeekAndDays = weekCost / dayCost; 

    int len = A.length;
    if (len == 0) return -1;

    if (len <= 3) return len * dayCost;

    int cost[] = new int[len];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
      int startIdx = i, endIdx = i + 1; 
      while (endIdx < len && A[endIdx]-A[startIdx] < sevenDays) 
        endIdx++;

      if (endIdx-startIdx > ratio_WeekAndDays)
      {
        if (endIdx >= startIdx + sevenDays) 
          endIdx = startIdx + sevenDays;  

        int j = startIdx;
        cost[j] = ((j == 0) ? 0 : cost[j-1]) + weekCost;

        while (++j < endIdx) {
          cost[j] = cost[j-1];
        }  
        i = j;
      }
      else
      {
        cost[i] = ((i == 0) ? 0 : cost[i-1]) + dayCost;
        i++;
      }  
    }
    int finalCost = Math.min(cost[len-1], monthCost);

    return finalCost;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find minimum cost of tickets in JavaScript 
case 1 : if input is [1,7,8,9,10] then the required output is 9
case 2 : if input is [1,7,8,9,10,15] then the required output is 11

```js
function calMinCosts(arr){
    if(!arr || arr.length===0)
        return 0;

    var len = arr.length; 
    var costsOfDateArr = Array.apply(null,{length:arr[len-1]+1}).map(()=>0);

    var price1=2,price2=7,price3=25;
    var days=7;

    var index=0,n=costsOfDateArr.length;
    for(var i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(i===arr[index]){
            if(i>=days+1){
                costsOfDateArr[i] = Math.min(costsOfDateArr[i-days-1]+price2, costsOfDateArr[i-1]+price1);
            }else{
                costsOfDateArr[i] = Math.min(costsOfDateArr[0]+price2, costsOfDateArr[i-1]+price1);
            }
            index+=1;
        }else{
            costsOfDateArr[i] = costsOfDateArr[i-1];
        }
    }

    return Math.min(price3,costsOfDateArr[n-1]);
}

console.log(calMinCosts([1,7,8,9,10]))
console.log(calMinCosts([1,7,8,9,10,15]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the C++ solution including print outs

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
int compute(std::vector<int> &A)
{
int sum[A.size()][A.size()+1];
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j < A.size(); j++)
    {
        sum[i][j]=2;
    }
}

for (int k = 0; k < A.size();k++)
{
    sum[k][A.size()]=0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < A.size(); j++)
    {
        if (i!=j)
        {
            if (sum[i][i] != 7)
            {
                int temp = abs(A[j]-A[i]);
                if (temp<7 && abs(j-i)>=3)
                {   
                    sum[i][i]=7;
                    sum[i][j]=7;
                    if (i>j)
                    {
                        for(int k = j;k < i;k++)
                            sum[i][k]=7;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(int k = i;k < j;k++)
                            sum[i][k]=7;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < A.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (sum[i][j]==7)
        {
            sum[i][A.size()]+=1;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < A.size()+1; ++j)
        std::cout<<sum[i][j]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}


int result = 0;
int row = A.size()-1;
int column = A.size()-1;
while(1)
{
    int value = sum[row][A.size()];
    if (value == 0)
        value=1;
    int temp = sum[row][column];
    result += temp;
    row = row-value;
    column = column-value;
    while (sum[row][column+1]==7 && row>=0)
    {
        row-=1;
        column-=1;
        result+=2;
    }
    if (row < 0)
        break;
}

return result;
}

int solution(std::vector<int> &A) {
if (A.size() > 24)
    return 25;
if (A.size() <= 3)
    return A.size() * 2;

return std::min(25,compute(A));
}

int main()
{
std::vector<int> AA={1,2,3,4,5,29,30};
std::vector<int> B={1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> A={1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,20,21};
std::vector<int> C={1,2,3,12};
std::vector<int> D={1,2,3,4,12,13,14,15,29,30};
std::vector<int> DD={1,2,3,4,5,14,17,18,19,20,23,28,29,30};
std::vector<int> CC={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,14,17,18,19,20,23,28,29,30};
std::cout<<solution(AA)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<solution(D)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<solution(B)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<solution(A)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<solution(C)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<solution(DD)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<solution(CC)<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```